# Identifying a late 90's early 2000's LEGO Space Fighter/Bomber

Tags: set-identification, star-wars

We're moving out some of our grown kids' LEGO sets that have been in storage for a long time.

We came across a bag with all these parts in it that look to be a LEGO space ship or bomber (I say this as the canopy is more rounded leading me to guess it to be a bomber of some type. I think a fighter might have a more angled rake on the windscreen.)

I have provided some photos too. I have looked through the entire database at eBay and could not find one like it. I don't think this is custom made. Although my boys can't remember what it is either, so I decided to try the Stack Exchange

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is [7673: Magna Guard Starfighter](https://brickset.com/sets/7673-1/Magna-Guard-Starfighter)

[image]

Comment: YES! Thank you very much Joost! This is a great looking ship!!!